# Returning a default value when query does not return rows in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

For a query I am using, a default value will need to be returned if no rows are returned (since the output will be used downstream).  The problem I'm encountering is how to programmatically identify that zero or null rows are returned so that the query knows to use the 'default' value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT fieldName from DB2Table
WHERE qualifier1 = '___'
AND qualifier2 = '___';
```

This can return either a value or nothing (as in, no rows at all). I've attempted using count(*), NOT NULL, and EXISTS() within a CASE Statement, but I've had no luck.

```
**Psuedocode**:
IF query returns values, return those
ELSE return "Some Value"
```

Any tips/insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the application executing the SQL statement unable to determine that there are *0* rows returned by the `select` statement and act appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query doesn't return a row and a default value needs to be returned in that case, use

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(
          (SELECT DISTINCT fieldName from DB2Table
          WHERE qualifier1 = '___' AND qualifier2 = '___'), 'DEFAULTVALUE'
        )
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: This will work if you add "from sysibm.sysdummy1" to the query.

Comment: Thank you! This was a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only expecting one row, then use aggregation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(fieldName, 'DEFAULT VALUE')
FROM DB2Table
WHERE qualifier1 = '___' AND qualifier2 = '___';
```

If you could be getting multiple rows, then here is another method:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT fieldName
      FROM DB2Table
      WHERE qualifier1 = '___' AND qualifier2 = '___'
     )
SELECT t.*
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEFAULT VALUE'
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t);
```